# Oracle Query With (BETWEEN Two Dates) Returns Empty Result Set

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an Oracle SQL Query I am trying to run, but it keeps returning null value for the second query  below but when I use the first query it returns a value. Please can someone help me check what I may be doing wrong in query 2? Note that the date column is in the Format **21/09/2020 10:00:00 AM** and I want to get all records from **22-SEP-2020 11:00:00 AM** to the current datetime for query 2. I am implementing query 2 for a Service, reason why I want to stick to it.

1. `SELECT query_date from Users where query_date > TO_DATE('21-SEP-2020 10:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')`
2. `SELECT query_date from Users where query_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('21-SEP-2020 10:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AND TO_DATE('22-SEP-2020 5:46:00 PM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS PM')`

Comment: Well, is the value returned by the first query after 22-SEP-2020 5:46:00 PM? (Incidentally, dates are stored with an internal representation, not with a specific format; your client will format that, using your NLS settings by default.)

Comment: If the query 1 returns rows but the query 2 none, it simple means that all `query_date` are greated that `22-SEP-2020 5:46:00 PM`. There is nothing wrong with this. Off topic, but otherwise, if query 2 would return rows, but query 1 not, it would mean that `query_date` is equal to `21-SEP-2020 10:00:00 AM`  which is excluded in query 1 but included in query 2 (BETWEEN is inclusive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to use `BETWEEN`, why not use `sysdate`?

```
WHERE query_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('21-SEP-2020 10:00:00 AM', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') AND sysdate
```